# Why does my array-shopping-list contain an "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Hello dear developers,

Each value of my array is supposed to have their own bullet on the html list - which they do. But there is an "undefined" before the actual list starts.
I wonder where it comes from. What is wrong with my code?

Thanks for your help!

HTML:

```
Shopping List
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

JS:

```
function letsShop(){
var array = ["milk", "cheese", "eggs"];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

var stuff = stuff + "<li>" + array[i] + "</li>";

document.getElementById("list").innerHTML=stuff;
}}

window.addEventListener("load", letsShop);
```

Comment: Move `var stuff` out of the loop and assign value to `stuff` inside the loop. `stuff = stuff + "<li>" + array[i] + "</li>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your stuff variable is declared inside loop which is not yet initialised that means returning undefined. Update you code like following:

```
function letsShop(){
  var array = ["milk", "cheese", "eggs"];
  var stuff = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    stuff +="<li>" + array[i] + "</li>";
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML=stuff;
  }
}

letsShop();
```

Answer (score 0):

`stuff` is `undefined` before the `for` loop runs. Plus, you're overwriting the contents of the list in the loop with each iteration.

The correct approach for this is:

```js
function letsShop() {
  // Declare the variable outside the loop
  var stuff = '';
  var array = ["milk", "cheese", "eggs"];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    stuff = stuff + "<li>" + array[i] + "</li>";
  }
  // Set the contents in list after the loop
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = stuff;
}

letsShop();
```

```html
Shopping List
<ul id="list"></ul>
```